# Curry Paste and Water 1:1 Sauce

Tags: sauce

I took a Thai cooking class offered by a restaurant I like a while ago, specifically hoping to learn how to make one dish they serve that I love. The class also came with a cookbook, including the recipe I had wanted.

My issue is that my sauce, which seems very simple, never turns out. The recipe calls for a 1:1 ratio of red curry paste and water (2 tbsp. of each, if I remember correctly offhand), gently mixed over low heat until it achieves the right consistency. A similar method worked for me in the class, but at home I was successful only once, and that involved some pretty wild ad hoc adjustments which I have not been able to reproduce. Usually the ingredients mix poorly in my saucepan, and no combination of heat, time, and attention prevents the outcome from being thick, uneven, and unpalatable.

I feel like I must be missing some essential step in the method, or the proportions of ingredients is simply not workable. Is this method, as presented in the cookbook, one that even sounds workable? And if so, what would more experienced cooks do to prepare this sauce?

Comment: Are you using exactly the same paste? Curry pastes and how they're meant to be used vary a lot.

Comment: @Chris H I can't speak to the paste used in the class, though I doubt the one I've been trying is the same. That's a good tip though, I'll definitely check out some of the Asian-focused grocery stores in my area for different pastes.

Comment: do you know the name (in English or Thai) of the dish?

Comment: Apart from checking the curry paste, you could try to start with more water and simmer a bit longer. Perhaps the paste would dissolve better?

Comment: @canardgras On the menu and in the cookbook the dish is called "Rama Thai Delight", and it's chicken in a peanut curry sauce served over steamed spinach. I have no idea if it's authentic or not.

Comment: @Stephie That's a good suggestion, I'll try it next time I attempt this dish and update this with the results.